# Django + Gunicorn with gevent workers, with asyncio in the views

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio, gunicorn, gevent

I have a django project, served by Gunicorn with gevent workers.

In some views, I have to make two long running external calls. These are IO-bound

```
class FooView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        slow_call_one()
        slow_call_two()
        do_some_work
        return HttpResponse(...)
```

There is no reason for which these two slow calls cannot run concurrently. Would there be any issue with running these as asyncio co-routines? I'm asking mainly regarding the interplay between asyncio and the gevent gunicorn workers.

My naïve understanding, based on the research that I've done is:

- Making these calls into asyncio coroutines would allow single requests to finish more quickly, by not sitting and waiting for IO bound tasks
- gunicorn + gevent workers allow multiple requests to run 'concurrently' (I am aware that it's not true concurrency).

My concerns are that gevent might already be transparently swapping to process a different request during the IO bound calls made by the original request, and that this might, at worst, screw up the process, or at best, not actually result in a performance improvement.

Comment: I'm exactly wondering about this issue! My current assumption is that because gevent's event loop and coroutine implementation are different from those of asyncio, when all coroutines of asyncio are in blocking I/O, then the whole thread will be blocked and any other reqeusts being processed in gevent's greenlet are also blocked and I'd better using same event loop and coroutine implementation in gunicorn worker and app's script code such as AsyncIO worker and asyncio coroutines. Of course it is just my assumption and I didn't event prove this myself. Would it be true?

Comment: Someone reported an issue doing this: https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/3053#issue-1847107636. It might not be a good idea to mix asyncio with gevent but I'm also still researching this.